# Change frame rate of a running processing animation

Tags: javascript, processing

I defined a processing animation running in the browser using [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)

I would like to change the [frame rate](http://processingjs.org/reference/frameRate_/) of the animation from the "outside" using javascript.
Is this possible at all? If so - how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution - it is trivial. Processing.js in fact exposes the processing methods to the javascript instance so that you can simply write:

```
p = Processing.getInstanceById('#canvas-id')
p.frameRate(20)
```

also long after the animation started.

Answer (score 0):

Processing has a framerate function check it out http://www.processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html

Comment: That's right, but it is "inside" the processing sketch and should be called in the setup function, whereas I want to do it from javascript, after a certain time (or on click).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having the same problem in Processing 2.2.1 (not running my program in the browser).

After trying to access the frameRate itself for a day, it came to me that you can just re-initiate setup() by key-press. As long as everything that changes on the screen is in global variables or draw(), you won't notice a change except for a little flicker (I was building a drum machine).

```
int tempo = 90;

void setup() {
  size(1000,600);
  frameRate((tempo / 60.0)*4.0);
}

void draw() {
  //whatever;
}

void keyPressed() {
  //+/- to control tempo (framerate)
    case '+':
      tempo += 1;
      setup();
      break;
    case '-':
      tempo -= 1;
      setup();
      break;
  }
```